# Passing default data for a controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to build a menu from an array in Laravel. What I'm currently doing is putting the array in a view

```
$menu = ['home', 'users' => ['create users' , 'update user', 'activity log']];
```

and then looping through it to generate the menu:

```
<section>
    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        @foreach($menu as $key => $nav)
            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="active">{{ $key }}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    @foreach($nav as $subnav)
                        <li>
                            <a href="">{{ $subnav }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</section>
```

Is there any other way that I can achieve the same result without putting the data in the view?

I also tried creating a constructor function in the controller:

```
public function __construct() {
    $menu = ['home', 'users' => ['create users' , 'update user', 'activity log']];

    return $menu;
}
```

But I guess that is not how it works. I appreciate any ideas on how I can go about this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have never used blade, but you should check for blade layouts: http://laravel.com/docs/views/templating#blade-layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using controller layouts you can bind data to the layout from within the constructor. Just make sure you call the parent constructor first so that the layout is instantiated properly.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->layout->menu = ['home', 'users' => ['create users' , 'update user', 'activity log']];
}
```

That will bind a `$menu` variable to the layout, and will also be available to any nested views that are used with Blades `@include`.

Comment: I get Creating default object from empty value when I do this

Comment: Perhaps you need to use with(). `$this->layout->with('menu', [])`

Answer (score 2):

[View composers](http://laravel.com/docs/views#view-composers) to the rescue!

They are executed every time before a view is rendered, so you can use this to pass standard data to them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at view composers:
http://www.laravel.com/docs/views#view-composers